# How to take the values from login with google response

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here i am having one multidimensional array , using this array i want to take from `emails` array i want to take user email value like `abc@gmail.com` and from `name` array i want to take value `givenName` like `Raju` and from `image` array i want to take `url` like `www.domain.com`

> print_r($user_info);

```
    Array
(
    [kind] => plus#person
    [etag] => "EhMivDE25UysA1M2v-A/ZXQsxHAN9QSz-hQoXfQGzFyLWdQ"
    [gender] => male
    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => abc@gmail.com
                    [type] => account
                )

        )

    [objectType] => person
    [id] => 100776010499118027035
    [displayName] => Raju r
    [name] => Array
        (
            [familyName] => r
            [givenName] => Raju
        )

    [url] => https://plus.google.com/100776010499118027035
    [image] => Array
        (
            [url] => www.domain.com
            [isDefault] => 
        )

    [isPlusUser] => 1
    [language] => en
    [circledByCount] => 1
    [verified] => 
    [domain] => www.facebook.com
)
```

> Expected Results

```
    abc@gmail.com

Raju

www.domain.com
```

> I tried like this

```
foreach($user_info['emails'] as $result){
        $user_email = $result['value'];
        foreach($result['name'] as $nameresult){
        $user_name = $nameresult['givenName'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: what was the response you got after trying the above? Also can you attach the json response that you got from google rather than printing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems name does not seems to be an array of arrays like emails. So you can directly take that name instead of inner loop

```
   foreach($user_info['emails'] as $result){
            $user_email = $result['value'];
        }
```

In this it the email value will  be overridden each time and will hold only last email element value.

&

```
$user_info['name']['familyName'];
$user_info['image']['url'];
```

What I understand from the above set of data is that a user will have multiple email ids and a one and one image url. So above logic works.